# Excel: Trigger double click event

Tags: excel, password-protection, double-click, vba

I have an Excel workbook that has been password protected by a third party. The interaction in that worksheet is done with double clicks to toggle check marks in fields. I would have to do 7000 double clicks to finish this task, so I would like to automate it. My suspicion is that the worksheet is using the BeforeDoubleClick event. The password encryption hides the actual implementation.

I started out running a test in my own worksheet, without a password, to rule those issues.

I have tried Application.DoubleClick:

```
Range("B17").Select
Application.DoubleClick
```

But that doesn't trigger my event code (Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick), which do work for "real" double clicks.

That is apparently by design according to MS:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220809(v=office.11).aspx

> The DoubleClick method doesn't cause this event to occur.

I can't call the third party event code directly, since the sub is private. Is there a way around this?

I have tried this both in Excel 2003 and 2007.

Comment: Hi,I have a same problem with your's.please tell me if you found any solution to solve it!I'm too confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is workaround that you can try (I tried this on Excel 2007)

1. Make the `BeforeDoubleClick` event public (I used this in Sheet1)

   > Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
2. In your macro simply call this function

   ```
   Range("B17").Select
   Call Sheet1.Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(Selection, False)
   ```

Comment: May I ask would you mind explaining why would this work?